# assign "this" classes to variables gives advantage?

Tags: javascript

I sometimes use `this` pointer while in `event` but sometimes I will use something like

```js
if (this.value < x && this.value < y && this.value == z)
```

is it better if I assigned it to variable to be

```js
var val = this.value;
if (val < x && val  < y && val  == z)
```

or no difference in performance or not because I do not know if `this.value` is registered or recalled every time used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can improve performance, in certain *old* Javascript engines - the engine *may* have to look up the `this` object and then look up the property descriptor / value for `value` before being able to evaluate `this.value`. For example, running the following code on IE11

```
(function() {
  const t0 = performance.now();
  const obj = { value: true };
  (function() {
    const value = this.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e8; i++) {
      this.value;
    }
  }).call(obj);
  const t1 = performance.now();
  console.log(t1 - t0);
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vmq9gb7o/4/

looks to take about *double* the time than running the same code with `this.value;` replaced with `value`: https://jsfiddle.net/vmq9gb7o/3/

But on modern browsers, the difference looks to be unnoticeable.

Even so, such an operation is *extremely* unlikely to be a performance bottleneck. If you're actually worried about performance, better to run an actual performance test. It's extremely likely that any bottlenecks found will *not* be in property lookups. In order to write high-quality, maintainable scripts, better to optimize them for *readability* first, and only worry about micro-optimizations if they actually prove to be an issue.

Best to avoid [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

That said, with this code in particular, it would be more DRY to extract the property into a standalone variable *once*, and then reference that standalone variable, so regardless of performance, your `var val = this.value;` version is probably preferable.